# How to add a border to a python console-menu

Tags: python, oop, console

I'm having some issues using the console-menu module for Python. I made my menu with the constructor and added a few items to it, but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to add formatting to it. There is a MenuStyle class in the documentation that I think I need to use:

```
classconsolemenu.format.MenuStyle(margins=None, padding=None, border_style=None, border_style_type=None, border_style_factory=None)
```

The full documentation is available here: https://console-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consolemenu.html
It's pretty short and to the point. I just don't understand what to do. Do I need to construct the border object and then use it in the ConsoleMenu() constructor? or add it in later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation it looks like you need to set ConsoleMenu's formatter argument to an instance of MenuFormatBuilder.  [example2.py](https://github.com/aegirhall/console-menu/blob/develop/examples/example2.py) has the following that might help you:

```
menu_format = MenuFormatBuilder().set_border_style_type(MenuBorderStyleType.HEAVY_BORDER) 
...
menu = ConsoleMenu("Root Menu", "This is the Root Menu Subtitle", formatter=menu_format)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask where you found that example? I haven't been able to find anything other than whats in the "usage" section of that documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to make example2.py a link. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Its a bit strange that the documentation makes no mention of the MenuFormatBuilder class anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too.  File a bug against the package.